# Aggregate values by a distinct identifier in Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

Here my table:
[image]

When I create a summed table by group_no I have below table in Power BI:

[image]

However, this is what I would like to have:

[image]

So, what I would like to get is total revenue by unique project_no on Groups (group_no).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

[image]

```
aggregated_revenue = 
VAR tbl = SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[project_no], 'Table'[revenue])
RETURN SUMX(tbl, 'Table'[revenue] )
```

Comment: You  have only dealt with the project_no and made it unique and the rest is just done by aggregating by group_no while creating the table. That has just done it!